# How to set TargetProperty of Storyboard in c#?

Tags: c#, animation, windows-runtime

I have this xaml code and I want to convert it in c#:

```
<Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="1"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

I have made different tries :

```
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            sb.Duration = duration;
            var da = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
            da.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
            da.Duration = duration;
            var ed1 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
            ed1.KeyTime = TimeSpan.Parse("0");
            ed1.Value = 1;
            var ed2 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
            ed2.KeyTime = TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:0.7");
            ed2.Value = 1;
            var ed3 = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
            ed3.KeyTime = TimeSpan.Parse("0:0:1");
            ed3.Value = 0;
            da.KeyFrames.Add(ed1);
            da.KeyFrames.Add(ed2);
            da.KeyFrames.Add(ed3);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, lgbStroke);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, "(Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset)");
            sb.Children.Add(da);
            sb.Begin();
```

but I get this exception :
**WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty (Shape.Stroke).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Offset) on specified object.**

Does anybody have any idea how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The stroke of the ellipse. I want to apply this animation on that stroke

Comment: It should be the ellipse if you look at the path you've specified. The first part of the path expects a `Shape`.